# UICollectionView cells are not moved correctly between sections during panning

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, realm, uicollectionviewlayout

To move items in a UICollectionView I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

I implemented the following gesture handler:

```
func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {break}
       collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Together with a correct override of the collection view delegate method `moveItemAtIndexPath`, moving cells within a section works perfect. Furthermore, moving cells to other visible sections also works as expected. However, problems occur when moving cells to sections that become visible by panning/scrolling down, resulting in the following error (I use a Realm database):

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

The problem seems related to the tracking of location changes by the gesture recognizer in  `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition` since the error occurs in this method.

I suppose that `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition` directly calls the collection view method `moveItemAtIndexPath` (not via the delegate) which results in an error since intermediate cell location changes are not updated in  the Realm database. Or am I incorrect?

Would anybody know why moving between sections works for visible sections, but not during panning? And how should the scrolling/panning be handled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView & UITableView APIs are very unforgiving when it comes to making updates in the UI state and requiring those to be mirrored in the data source.

You need to update the Realm to reflect the UI state in order to keep UICollectionView happy.

Here's an example of a Realm-backed UITableViewController with reorderable cells that you could adapt for your UICollectionView use case:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ObjectList: Object {
    let list = List<DemoObject>()
}

class DemoObject: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var items: List<DemoObject>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.editing = true

        let realm = try! Realm()
        if realm.isEmpty {
            try! realm.write {
                let list = ObjectList()
                list.list.appendContentsOf(["one", "two", "three"].map {
                    DemoObject(value: [$0])
                })
                realm.add(list)
            }
        }
        items = realm.objects(ObjectList.self).first!.list
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items?[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return .None
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        guard let items = items else { return }
        try! items.realm?.write {
            let itemToMove = items[fromIndexPath.row]
            items.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
            items.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I basically implemented for a collection view and works without problems in case of a single section (and in a table view also for multiple sections with an appropriate `moveRowAtIndexPath`). The issue I encounter only occurs when I pan a moving cell beyond the last cell of a section in a multi-section collection view (with a single section no error occurs). I published some code where this error can be reproduced on [github](https://github.com/Taco55/CollectionViewCellMoving). Could this be a
bug in Swift or do I update the database incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated